# Отключение USB накопителей через групповые политики

Tags: usb, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Имеется домен на Windows Server 2008 R2. Была создана групповая политика для ограничения доступа:

*Конфигурация  пользователя -> Политики -> Административные шаблоны:определение политик (ADMX-шаблоны)получены с локального компьютера -> Система -> Доступ к съемным запоминающим устройствам:*

*Съемные запоминающие устройства всех классов: Запретить любой доступ - **Включена***

После этого, во вкладке "Делегирование" добавил в исключение группу пользователей:

[image: Параметры безопасности]

Сама политика работает - USB-флешки ни у кого не работают, но вот исключения не действуют.

Вопрос: где ошибка?

Comment: здравствуйте могу ли я сделать так дать доступ определенным устройствам и закрыть для других устройств если да то как мне это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась путём изменения настроек делегирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. gpupdate /force обязательно после изменения.